# How to measure how long file related system calls are taking in perf?

Tags: linux, profiling, perf, strace

I have an application which is running unusually slow. I have reason to suspect that this may be because some specific files are slower to read from and stat.

I know I can use strace to get timing information, but I'd prefer to use perf because the overhead is so much lower.

Brendan Gregg has some helpful examples of using perf:

http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html

But his first system call example only shows aggregate timings across all calls and I need per-file timings. His second system call example doesn't include timings, and only shows fd numbers, not real paths.

How do I piece this together? I'm looking to get something similar to what I would get from “strace -Tttt -e trace=file”.

Added bonus would be if I can measure cycles at the same time.

Comment: Use `perf record ...`, `perf script` instead of `perf stat ...`.

Comment: @Zulan I separately know of those commands, but I don't know how to make them acheive what I described.

Comment: 1) Read the man pages. 2) Run `perf record ... ` just as you would run `perf stat ...` as perf the examples 3) Run `perf script`. If you have specific issues with that update your question.

Comment: @Zulan That doesn't remotely help. You may as well write, "Use the tool"

Comment: Well you don't tell us what you actually already tried... So I guess my assumption about where you are at were wrong. Please include what you have tried so far to move on...

Answer (score 3):

Output from  `strace -Tttt -e trace=file` is trace (tracing tool), and perf is usually used as profiling tool (aggregating time spent in function by name -  in `perf record` by default on time or on hardware events + `perf report`, `perf top` modes) or as statistics tool (in `perf stat` mode - with counting of some events over all running time of the program).

You should try some tracing tool ([`trace-cmd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/trace-cmd.1.html), [`sysdig`](https://sysdig.com/opensource/), [lttng](https://lttng.org/), ...) or you can try to use `perf` in tracing modes (`perf record` with tracepoints and `perf script` to output non-aggregated log over time)

There are tracepoints for syscalls (`syscalls       614`): 
http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html#Tracepoints 
http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html#StaticKernelTracing

```
perf record -e 'syscalls:sys_*' ./program
perf script
```

Example of output with format: process_name, pid, [cpu_core], time_since_boot_seconds.microseconds:, tracepoint_name, tracepoint_arguments

```
          ls 19178 [001]  16529.466566:                   syscalls:sys_enter_open: filename: 0x7f6ae4c38f82, flags: 0x00080000, mode: 0x
          ls 19178 [001]  16529.466570:                    syscalls:sys_exit_open: 0x4
          ls 19178 [001]  16529.466570:               syscalls:sys_enter_newfstat: fd: 0x00000004, statbuf: 0x7ffe22df92f0
          ls 19178 [001]  16529.466572:                syscalls:sys_exit_newfstat: 0x0
          ls 19178 [001]  16529.466573:                   syscalls:sys_enter_mmap: addr: 0x00000000, len: 0x00042e6f, prot: 0x00000001,
          ls 19178 [001]  16529.466767:                    syscalls:sys_exit_mmap: 0x7f6ae4df8000
          ls 19178 [001]  16529.466768:                  syscalls:sys_enter_close: fd: 0x00000004
          ls 19178 [001]  16529.466769:                   syscalls:sys_exit_close: 0x0
```

You may also try `perf record -g -e  'syscalls:sys_*'` to record function backtrace (to get information which function of the application did the syscall, and who did call this function; works better with debug information).

perf as tracing tool may not decode syscall (tracepoint) arguments; and tracing tools like trace-cmd or lttng may decode them better (at least decoding file name in open syscall).